# Cannot break do-while loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, do-while, restart, application-pool

I have been working on this PowerShell script. I'm still pretty new at this. The way it works is that I give it a list of servers which it goes though and restarts the App Pools 1 by 1. I have been having a problem with the snippet below. I do not use Restart-WebAppPool because it sometimes gives the App Pool a start before it's ready and leaves it stopped. I cannot show the whole script because it's big and has proprietary info. The problem that I'm having is I can't seem to break the do-while loop. In it I'm checking App Pool status to make sure that it's stopped.

What I get appears for $PL_Break appears to be a valid string showing "Stopped". However, even when it shows "Stopped" it doesn't break the loop.

$PL_Timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 95

foreach ($PL_Server in $PL_ServerName)
{
$PL_Stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

```
Write-host "`n`n`nRestarting App Pool : $PL_AppPool"
write-host "Stopping: " $PL_Server -f Green

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PL_Server -ArgumentList $PL_AppPool -ScriptBlock {param($PL_App) Stop-WebAppPool -Name $PL_App} 

do {

sleep 5
$PL_Br = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PL_Server -ArgumentList $PL_AppPool -ScriptBlock {param($PL_App) Get-IISAppPool $PL_App | Select-Object State}

$PL_Break = [string]$PL_Br.State.value

} while (($PL_Stopwatch.elapsed -lt $PL_Timeout) -or ($PL_Break -ne "Stopped"))
```

} # Foreach - Server

Comment: you're looking for `-and` instead of `-or` - `$PL_Stopwatch` and `$PL_Timeout` are not defined in your code by the way, I hope they're in your actual script.

Comment: I'm using or on purpose because I want it to break if it reaches the timeout or the App Pool successfully stops. I've used this specific type of loop in other scripts. I do have the timeout defined earlier in the script. This specific case is giving me trouble because when the timeout hasn't yet run out and the App Pool successfully stops, I get a string for $PL_Break that indicates it's stopped, but the loop doesn't break.

Comment: read it in English, I think you're misunderstanding your loop breaking condition... you want to 
__loop__ _while the timer is below the timeout OR the variable is not equal to stopped_ or _while the timer is below the timeout AND the variable is not equal to stopped_ ?

Comment: I want it to loop until either the timer expires or the App Pool stops. If it is equal to "Stopped" it should break the loop.

Comment: but you are saying to keep running the loop while EITHER of those are true

Comment: maybe you are looking for Until instead of While?

Comment: @Daniel thanks, not sure if I'm explaining it wrong.. _run this loop while either this OR this is `$true`_, where OP wants _run this loop while BOTH conditions are `$true` (ergo, `-and`)_

Comment: Explanation sounds good to me :)  I guess I would rather write this like `do { ... } until (($PL_Stopwatch.elapsed -gt $PL_Timeout) -or ($PL_Break -eq "Stopped"))`

Comment: AAHH... lightbulb! Thanks I see what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: That did it. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: I used d-while only because it's more familiar to me from other languages and I've used it before. I'll try do-until next ime. Thanks for the advise! That does look more legible.